# Adyen drop-in Checkout SDK failing on validation

Tags: adyen

I am trying to use drop-in Checkout using the guide here:
https://docs.adyen.com/developers/checkout/web-sdk

I can successfully see the payment screen but I get warnings in the console:

> WARNING: securedFields:: the encryption algorithm is not present. It will not be possible to encrypt input fields

and as soon as I enter the credit card details I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: adyen.createEncryption is not a function
>      at Object.a._createEncryption (securedFields.1.3.0.min.js:79)
>      at Object.a._getEncryptedData (securedFields.1.3.0.min.js:81)
>      at n (securedFields.1.3.0.min.js:326)
>      at A (securedFields.1.3.0.min.js:313)
>      at o.processValidationsObj (securedFields.1.3.0.min.js:320)
>      at HTMLInputElement.n (securedFields.1.3.0.min.js:209)

In the browser console "adyen" is not defined.
Any suggestion?

[image: console]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this was resolved by Adyen support.

It was due to the merchant account being setup as Point of Sale (POS). 
Creating  new "eCommerce" account solved the issue.